# How exactly is immutability handled in Corda

Tags: corda

Since the data is stored in RDBMS it could be accessed and changed later at any point by any party.

And any reference to the changed data could be a problem.

Does the notaries storage (which can't be queried) or the Merkle trees play the role?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Immutability is handled in Corda through the use of digital signatures.

You are correct in saying that Corda transactions are backed by RDBS, however, you wouldn't be able to change 'data' without invalidating the signatures that have been applied to them.

The Notary doesn't act as secondary storage, the Notary (or rather Notaries as they always operate in clusters) is responsible for preventing double spends.

A simple example might be, I create a transaction where I send you 3 tokens, we both sign this transaction to make it valid (according to some contract rules we've defined). If you were to then change the 'data' backing this transaction to instead reflect 4 tokens, you would invalidate the signatures.

You could recreate your own signature, but you wouldn't be able to recreate mine. If you now tried to spend this state reflecting 4 tokens, it would be rejected by the new receiving party.

Comment: Which means corda has data stored at transaction level as well, so that the change in the DBMS can be identified and invalidated, please clarify.